# Multiple color change

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have 8 navigation link page. Each link is planet which has 3 button and by clicking them info is shown. Each planet has its own color, so for example, when I`m clicking Mercury, these 3 button should have blue background color when i click and also, by default, first button should have blue background color. If I click next nav-link Venus, first button should have yellow bg color and by clicking other buttons, bg color switching to current button. https://codepen.io/einstyr/pen/ZEjVaYw source code

Problem is that I made this with JS element.style.backgroundColor but than I can`t add hover effect with CSS and I don`t want to make hover effect with JS bc I know there is some good solution. I tried with data-attributes but removing all 8 planet`s attributes would be crazy. Any ideas?

Comment: far to complicated. Use an eventListener for mouseover and make use of the event delegation and `target` function

Comment: It might be better to, instead of using `style.backgroundColor`, to use CSS variables, which you can reference and use where and when you want. `.style.setProperty( '--planet-color', 'red' )`, then refer to it in css with something like `color: var(--planet-color, blue)`. Those will animate, transition etc...

Comment: This may depend on your specific scenario, which I'm not completely sure about… In the case of having them all the same color before you hover over one, I would consider `CSS` `filter`. You could easily make all of them all white, or all black, or even just grayscale. Then you'd be able to set the color of each, in the `CSS`, and transition the `filter`, rather than the color.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://codepen.io/einstyr/pen/ZEjVaYw I included link in original post but somehow didn`t show. Here is a codepen link if someone has time to look at it.